# How to calculate this function for both Ethereum networks mainnet and ropsten getBlockTimestamp().add(delay)?

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation, etherscan, uniswap, timelock

I have a question:

How to calculate this function for both Ethereum networks mainnet and ropsten getBlockTimestamp().add(delay)?

I installed web3.eth and tried web3.eth.getBlockTimestamp().add(delay) but it did not work. I would appreciate it if you could help me in this.

Answer (score 1):

[`web3.eth`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth.html) does not have a method named `getBlockTimestamp()`.

I think you are confusing the Web3 JS package with the Solidity smart contract language.

For reference: `getBlockTimestamp.add(delay)` appears in Compound's `Timelock.sol` contract, which is [here](https://github.com/compound-finance/compound-protocol/blob/master/contracts/Timelock.sol).